# Filter not working in ag-grid-community version 26.1.0

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular, angular12

I am trying to implement filters using ag-grid.

```
<ag-grid-angular
 class="ag-blue"
 style="width:100%; height:300px;"
 [gridOptions]="grid"
 [rowData]="data"
 enableSorting></ag-grid-angular>
```

Now, this filter used to work for ag-grid version 15.0.0. I recently updated it to version 26.2.0 and it has stopped working.

But, if I change the class to "ag-theme-blue" then it starts working. So, I would like to know if anything changed between this versions? and if none, then how to implement with that class="ag-blue".

```
<ag-grid-angular
 class="ag-theme-blue"
 style="width:100%; height:300px;"
 [gridOptions]="grid"
 [rowData]="data"
 enableSorting></ag-grid-angular>
```